# Unity 2D: Chase AI That Avoids Obstacles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to make a game object, in this case an enemy, continuously chase after the player while avoiding obstacles.⠀

I'm casting two rays to detect any obstacles and then, if there are obstacles, change the velocity so it avoids them. However, the enemy struggles when the player circles around an obstacle. It continues to follow the player when moving out of the way so it ends up running into the obstacle, gets stuck and sometimes moves in the opposite direction.

```
//private int range = 3;
//private float speed = 1.0f;
//LayerMask obstacles = LayerMask.GetMask("Obstacles");

public void MoveToTarget(Transform _target)
{  
    Vector2 _dir = _target.position - transform.position;
    RaycastHit2D _hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position - new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), _dir, range, obstacles);
    RaycastHit2D _hitTwo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), _dir, range, obstacles);
    
    if (_hit.collider != null || _hitTwo.collider != null)
    {
        dir = Vector2.Perpendicular(_hit.normal);
    }

    rb.velocity = _dir.normalized * speed;
}
```

It will continue to follow the player given enough time but it stops for moment before resuming to chase. I've tried playing around with the range of the raycast, speed of the enemy and size of the obstacle but those don't make any difference.

Comment: What you describe sounds a bit like [Boids](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=unity+boids) .. usually boids are more for larger groups of objects but can be used for single objects as well. Basically you let your object move "freely" but apply a certain set of rules - like e.g. avoid obstacles, follow the player. Then the Boid resolves the weights of both and behaves accordingly (like e.g. if avoid obstacles has a higher priority/weight than the follow player this will always overrule .. if its a risk it is allowed to take you make the follow player higher prio etc)

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for your comment! I did some research on Boids and, from what I understand, I should set vector points around the enemy and then cast rays to those points. If the point closest to the player is obstructed by an obstacle, I should try the next closest point, and etc. (For the individual agents.)

Comment: Either this or you go for [`NavMeshAgent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NavMeshAgent.html) especially if the map is static it can use proper path finding and you only have to update its target position .. see [Tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/navigation-basics#)

Answer (score 0):

A concept that can help you to develop such game AI is called [steering behaviours](https://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/). There are all kinds of applications scenarios for each of those, as well on what techniques you'll use to apply them properly.

The scenario you're describing you can mix-up two steering behaviours: **Pursuit** and **Collision Avoidance**.

I'd also recommend you to take a look at some common path-fiding algorithms such as [A*](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/a-search-pathfinding-algorithm-in-c/) and [Dijkstra](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/csharp-program-for-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/)

Comment: I see, so rather than my code being the issue it is my method and how I am approaching the problem.

Comment: Exactly - and in fact, you're coding it correctly when properly using raycasts and other physics to determinate the movement/behaviour. That's how we grab info from the game-area!

Comment: Thank you! I've coded much more basic AI before but I'm quite new when it comes to more complicated AI like this. I'll do some research on steering behaviours and the path-finding algorithms you mentioned. Thank you again!